# How do I go to a previous activity after the current one has been in paused state

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have two activities A & B. A start B like this

```
Intent mainPage = new Intent( MainActivity.this, Profile.class );
    Bundle extraMain = new Bundle();
    extraMain.putString( "userName", userName );
    extraMain.putString( "memberNo", memberNo );
    mainPage.putExtras( extraMain );
    startActivity( mainPage );
```

then B can go back to A like this

```
B.this.finish();
```

this process works fine until when activity B is paused and then resumed and try to go back to A. Instead of finishing B and resume A it goes to the device home screen.

Here is the manifest code for the 2 activities. MainActivity is A and Profile is B.

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    <activity
        android:name="profile.Profile"
        android:launchMode = "singleInstance" />
```

I think I might not have handled the states of the activities properly, please help

Comment: Can you explain a bit more. What do you exactly want to do?

Comment: Since activity A starts B, I need the user to be able to go back to activity A after they have been to another app or home screen. The problem I am having is that when the user resumes the application and tries to go to A it leaves the application completely and goes to the device home screen. below is the manifest code for the two activities. MainActivity is A and Profile is B

Comment: can you update your question with Manifest.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this part of the code:

```
android:launchMode = "singleInstance"
```

You're forcing it to only maintain a [single instance](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en).

Get rid of that and it will do as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by finishing Activity in onPaused method like this

```
@Override
public void onPause() 
{
    super.onPause();
    B.this.finish();
}
```

Comment: problem persists. It can go to activity A

Answer (score 0):

This state is occurred when activity A is cleared from memory.
for a practice override all activity life cycle methods shown in pic and print some log to see what is happening.

[Activity Life Cycle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wwPM.jpg)

there is two solution to solve this and its up to you to chose which one.

first solution :

instead of this line of your code

```
B.this.finish();
```

use

```
B.this.onBackPressed();
```

and your activity A will launch.

second solution:

finish activity A when you are opening activity B then in Activity B just start activity A again instead of `B.this.finish();`

you can read this [blog](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en) for better information about activities life cycle and launch mode